# Excel formula to answer if text in cell a1 is found in column H1:H385 it should display the data from the neighbouring cell I1:I385

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am struggling to write this formula in excel and I would really appreciate some advice.

I am looking to identify if the data in cell a1, is present in the list of data in h1:385, if it is present within the list, I would like the data to display the neighbouring cells data from i1:i385.

So for example a1 data= "tom", h383= "tom", i383 = "english". So the formula would have identified h383 as containing the same data as a1, I would then like it to display the data from i383.

Thanks so much, Tom.

Comment: Use ***VLOOKUP()*** or a combination of ***MATCH()*** and ***INDEX()***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few methods to do this, but my preferred one is an `Index` and `Match` combination:

```
=INDEX($I:$I,MATCH($A1,$H:$H,0))
```

`Index` will index the entire range in column I, and `Match` will search column H for the value in A1, and return in which row it is found. `Index` will then return the value on that row from column I.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!